# Unable to inject the custom JavaScript in .Net Core 2.2 in swagger

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle, asp.net-core-2.2, .net-core-2.2

I have written a JavaScript which I would like to inject in swagger with .Net Core 2.2. I would like to highlight that **wwwroot** folder wasn't created by default when I created web project (empty project option) with .Net Core 2.2. I then created **wwwroot** folder manually and added my JavaScript file inside that. When I am launching swagger, I am getting an error that file couldn't be loaded. I tried to create a folder "**swagger**" inside **wwwroot** and place a file there but that too didn't work.
Here is my sample code:

```
SwaggerUIOptions uiConfig;
uiConfig.InjectJavascript("mycustomfile.js");
```

Also I would like to highlight what I am trying to achieve here. I got a drop-down in my header for a database provided i.e. `Oracle/MSSQL` etc. Now based on the selection, I want to change the value of another header i.e. connection string. I have written a JavaScript for this purpose but let me know if that can be achieved in some other and simplistic way as well with .Net Core along with`Swashbuckle`.

Comment: Can you access your "mycustomfile.js" from the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue got resolved after using `app.UseStaticFiles();` in `Configure()` method.